# Curl Download from Artifactory Repository

Tags: curl, sed, artifactory

I currently have a folder structure populated on our Artifactory service as so.
(Example)

```
https://MYARTIFACTORYSERVIER/artifactory/mypath/releases/1.01zsomefilec5e5070b.zip
25-Jan-2022 09:49
https://MYARTIFACTORYSERVIER/artifactory/mypath/releases/2.01zsomefilec1e3070b.zip
03-Mar-2022 14:46 
https://MYARTIFACTORYSERVIER/artifactory/mypath/releases/3.01zsomefilec556073b.zip
08-Jul-2022 12:27 
https://MYARTIFACTORYSERVIER/artifactory/mypath/releases/4.01zsomefile25e5370b.zip
11-Jul-2022 12:27
```

I'm using CURL to try and grab the latest version (4.01) which also has the latest timestamp and copy to my local c:\temp (Windows) using shell

```
ART=https://MYARTIFACTORYSERVIER/artifactory/mypath/releases

curl .. "$ART/" > "*somefile*.*zip"

LATEST=$(sed -ne '/href=/{s@.*href=".*/\([0-9]\+_[^"]\+\).*@\1@p}' < "*somefile*.*zip" | sort -nr | head -1)

curl --insecure -o c:\\temp\\testfile.zip ... "$ART/$LATEST"
```

This does run but I get the list of releases as shown at the top here and a file created but the file does not contain the correct data in the zip. (and not the latest zip file which i hoped)

If I run a standard curl looking at the direct file only this works fine I.E

```
curl -o c:\temp\somefile.zip "https://MYARTIFACTORYSERVIER/artifactory/mypath/releases/1.01zsomefilec5e5070b.zip"
```

Any thoughts? Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Stan.

Comment: Taking you on a different path - you should be able to let Artifactory do the heavy lifting for you using a custom "Repository Layout" and the "Retrieve Latest Artifact" API. See the following documentation:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

Comment: Also see the following article in the KB: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-simple-versioning-custom-layout-in-artifactory/

Comment: If all you want is for your script to work, you can try this instead to get the latest:
LATEST=$(grep -e '.*href=.*\.zip"' < "*somefile*.*zip" | sed -e 's/.*href="//' | sed -e 's/\.zip".*/.zip/' | sort -nr | head -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifactory can do the heavy lifting for you, making the script redundant.

Artifactory supports defining a custom layout for repositories. The layout is useful for several use cases, one of them is resolving the latest version of an artifact.

More information can be found in the following links:

- Documentation: [Repository Layouts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts)
- Documentation: [Artifactory REST API - Retrieve Latest Artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact)
- Knowledge base: [How to create simple versioning custom layout in Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-simple-versioning-custom-layout-in-artifactory/)

Comment: i would still like to try and get the script working above for my curiosity and also because its going to take me an age to get these changes made on the artifactory instance